# Python 3, filling out a form with request (library) returns same page HTML without inputting parameters

Tags: python, html, selenium, python-requests, mechanize

I am trying to use requests to fill out a form on https://www.doleta.gov/tradeact/taa/taa_search_form.cfm and return the HTML of the new page that this opens and extract information from the new page.

Here is the relevant HTML

```
  <form action="taa_search.cfm" method="post" name="number_search" id="number_search" onsubmit="return validate(this);">
    <label for="input">Petition number</label>
    :
    <input name="input" type="text" size="7" maxlength="7" id="input">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_name" value="number_search" />
    <input type=submit value="Get TAA information" />
  </form>
```

Here is the python code I am trying to use.

```
url = 'https://www.doleta.gov/tradeact/taa/taa_search.cfm'
payload = {'number_search':'11111'}
r = requests.get(url, params=payload)
with open("requests_results1.html", "wb") as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

When you perform the query manually, this page opens https://www.doleta.gov/tradeact/taa/taa_search.cfm.

However, when I use the above Python code, it returns the HTML of https://www.doleta.gov/tradeact/taa/taa_search_form.cfm (the first page) and nothing is different.

I cannot perform similar code on https://www.doleta.gov/tradeact/taa/taa_search.cfm because it redirects to the first URL and thus, running the code returns the HTML of the first URL.

Because of the permissions setup of my computer, I cannot redirect the path of my PC (which means Selenium is off the table) and I cannot install Python 2 (which means mechanize is off the table). I am open to using urllib but do not know the library very well.

I need to perform this action ~10,000 times to scrap the information. I can build the iteration part myself, but I cannot figure out how to get the base function to work properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first observation is that you seem to be using a `get` request in your example code instead of a `post` request.

```
<form action="taa_search.cfm" method="post" ...>
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

After changing to a `post` request, I was still getting the same results as you though (html from the main search form page). After a bit of experimentation, I seem to be able to get the proper html results by adding a `referer` to the header.

Here is the code (I only commented out the writing to file part for example purposes):

```
import requests

BASE_URL = 'https://www.doleta.gov/tradeact/taa'


def get_case_decision(case_number):
    headers = {
        'referer': '{}/taa_search_form.cfm'.format(BASE_URL)
    }
    payload = {
        'form_name': 'number_search',
        'input': case_number
    }
    r = requests.post(
        '{}/taa_search.cfm'.format(BASE_URL),
        data=payload,
        headers=headers
    )
    r.raise_for_status()
    return r.text
    # with open('requests_results_{}.html'.format(case_number), 'wb') as f:
    #     f.write(r.content)
```

Testing:

```
>>> result = get_case_decision(10000)
>>> 'MODINE MFG. COMPANY' in result
True
>>> '9/12/1980' in result
True
>>> result = get_case_decision(10001)
>>> 'MUSKIN CORPORATION' in result
True
>>> '2/27/1981' in result
True
```

Since you mentioned that you need to perform this ~10,000 times, you will probably want to look into using [`requests.Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) as well.